# sed find and replace, but only in text blocks between matching patterns

Tags: awk, sed

I have a SQL dump file. There are many tables, one of which contains a column I would like to set to null before final archiving.

The dump file has a structure like:

```
COPY public.my_target_table (id, name, content_type_id, codename) FROM stdin;
1   Can add association 1   add_association
2   Can change association  1   change_association
<..................>


COPY public.table_2 (id, name, content_type_id, codename) FROM stdin;
1   Can add association 1   add_association
2   Can change association  1   change_association
```

The values are tab-separated. My initial idea was to `sed` find/replace between the appropriate indices, but I realized I will need to only do so for one specific table (otherwise I am wiping data from all tables, at that index).

Is there a way to tell `sed` to only operate once it has passed the string `my_target_table`, and disable when it has reached the next blank line?

*edit for clarity*

Using the example above, the goal is to output:

```
COPY public.my_target_table (id, name, content_type_id, codename) FROM stdin;
1   \N  1   add_association
2   \N  1   change_association
<..................>


COPY public.table_2 (id, name, content_type_id, codename) FROM stdin;
1   Can add association 1   add_association
2   Can change association  1   change_association
```

...assuming my memory is correct and `\N` means null. Ideally the answer can be extended to any target table and column index (or even better, target table and column name :) ). Also, I'm not limited to `sed` - I have heard `awk` might be a useful tool here as well?

Comment: Could you please post expected sample output in your question and let us know then?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 edited for more detail!

Comment: Why not just append the SQL (or equivalent dump syntax) of the desired change to the dump?

Comment: @jhnc the volume of data (json history snapshots) in that one column is prohibitive for the remote development team that consumes this dump file, by stripping it out entirely I can drastically reduce their bandwidth use.

Comment: How are tabs, ie. the field delimiters, escaped in the data?

Comment: @JamesBrown Honestly I'm not positive since I haven't seen any in the dumps yet, but I would wager `\t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed` how about:

```
tab=$'\t'
sed "
/my_target_table/ { n
:l
s/^\\([^$tab]*$tab\\)[^$tab]*/\\1\\\\N/
n
/[^[:blank:]]/b l
}" file
```

Output for the provided sample:

```
COPY public.my_target_table (id, name, content_type_id, codename) FROM stdin;
1       \N      1       add_association
2       \N      1       change_association
<..................>


COPY public.table_2 (id, name, content_type_id, codename) FROM stdin;
1       Can add association     1       add_association
2       Can change association  1       change_association
```

- Considering the posix `sed` which does not support the `\t` notation,
  assign a shell variable `tab` to a tab character at the beginning.
- if the pattern `/my_target_table/` is found, execute the sed command
  between `{` and `}`.
- `:l` creates a label for `b` command.
- `s/^\\([^$tab]*$tab\\)[^$tab]*/\\1\\\\N/` replaces the second field
  of the line separated by tab with a string `\N`.
- `n` prints out the current pattern space and read the next line.
- `/[^[:blank:]]/b l` loops to the label `l` until the line is blank.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably an easier way, but this works:

```
BEGIN { OFS=FS="\t" }
/my_target_table/ { s = 1; print; next }
/^$/ { s = 0 }
(NF>1) && (s==1) { $2 = "<redacted>" }
1
```

---

awk -f script.awk sql_dump

```
COPY public.my_target_table (id, name, content_type_id, codename) FROM stdin;
1   <redacted>  1   add_association
2   <redacted>  1   change_association
<..................>


COPY public.table_2 (id, name, content_type_id, codename) FROM stdin;
1   Can add association 1   add_association
2   Can change association  1   change_association
```